# Unable to reach RabbitMQ management console over SSL

Tags: debian, ssl, rabbitmq

I'm having a strange problem. I have installed RabbitMQ on Debian 12. There was a small issue during installation - I could not pass dependency of erlang-crypto with libssl1.1 - the one which I had on my system was not compatible with that package, I had to manually download libssl1.1_1.1.1n-0+deb11u5_amd64.deb package to move along with the installation process. I started with default configuration, added management console plugin and everything was working fine.

Then I have added SSL/TLS support for both broker and its management console and from server's side it looks good. Here is the management section from rabbitMQ diagnostics:

```
Enabled plugins:

 * rabbitmq_management
 * rabbitmq_management_agent
 * rabbitmq_web_dispatch
 * amqp_client
 * cowboy
 * cowlib

Interface: 0.0.0.0, port: 15671, protocol: https, purpose: HTTP API over TLS (HTTPS)
Interface: [::], port: 25672, protocol: clustering, purpose: inter-node and CLI tool communication
Interface: [::], port: 5672, protocol: amqp, purpose: AMQP 0-9-1 and AMQP 1.0
Interface: [::], port: 5671, protocol: amqp/ssl, purpose: AMQP 0-9-1 and AMQP 1.0 over TLS
```

The port is open and it listens:

```
tcp             LISTEN           0                1024                             0.0.0.0:15671                          0.0.0.0:*              users:(("beam.smp",pid=439,fd=38))
```

However I am not able to reach it - browser can't open the page giving connection error as soon as I enter in the URL - This site can’t be reached The connection was reset.

I am not able to connect to the broker using .NET connection. It is nothing client side - I am able to reach SSL services of other hosts, also I'm able to reach other RabbitMQ management console on the other server having identical configuration file.

There is no firewall installed on Debian host - RabbitMQ is the only service running on  it.

Any idea what can be happening?

Krzysztof